# Disable unneeded OAuth endpoints spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, swagger

I have an authorization server and resource server contained under one single spring boot application. I only want to enable the password flow.

I believe that would mean I only need the /oauth/token endpoint, however my swagger UI is configured to autofind all endpoints and shows:

- authorization-endpoint(/oauth/authorize)
- check-token-endpoint (/oauth/check_token)
- token-endpoint (/oauth/token)
- whitelabel-approval-endpoint (/oauth/confirm_access)
- whitelabel-error-endpoint (/oauth/error)

As per the spring-security-oauth2-boot src code:

> Spring Security access rule for the check token endpoint (e.g. a SpEL expression like "isAuthenticated()") . Default is empty, which is interpreted as "denyAll()" (no access).

This is the same for the token key endpoint.

If all access is denied to this endpoint by default and I am not changing them, should I turn them off completely/is there a way. Also, if i cannot disable them, can i disable them in the swagger docs auto configure to reduce clutter?

Comment: https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: That link describes that these endpoints are created but does not show if i can disable /oauth/error, /oauth/confirm_access, /oauth/check_token, and /oauth/authorize